# keyPressed() does not activate in p5

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to spawn a lightsource in my 3D-space using keyPressed(). However, upon pressing keys on the keyboard, nothing happens. I did as instructed in this following tutorial, and can't see what's the difference with his and my code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UvSjtiW-RH8

I have tried to look for differences between the tutorial and my program, and I have tried to use something else than a light source as the object/event to be activated with keyPressed() (for example I tried changing the background color).

```
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
    background(100);

    push();
    ambientMaterial(255, 255, 255);
    rotateY(angle);
    rotateX(angle);
    sphere(300);
    translate(200, 300);
    sphere(50);
    pop();
}

function keyPressed() {
    pointLight(255, 55, 255, 10, 200, 400);
}
```

I expected to see the light upon pressing a key on my keyboard, but this does not happen. No error messages are shown.

Comment: The key is detected just fine, as you will notice if you add something like `alert("key press")` to the function. The problem is that calling the light function a) like that and b) only once does nothing. You need to call it in your `draw()` loop function, and before adding the sphere. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/p503ers8/

Comment: Thank you! I understand, great answer! I'll post it here to mark the question as "solved".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by Chris G:

The key is detected just fine, as you will notice if you add something like alert("key press") to the function. The problem is that calling the light function a) like that and b) only once does nothing. You need to call it in your draw() loop function, and before adding the sphere. Example: jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/p503ers8

I think this completely answers my question and therefore I'll post it here as an accepted answer!